# Implementing cut, copy and paste

Tags: android

I m new in android platform and trying to build a file manager app. I have done upto using intents to open any file and gave the specific icons for specific files. Now i would like to implement cut, copy and paste in my file browser so that I can **cut/copy/paste any file/folder** in my app.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score -1):

Simply create string (path to file) variable that simulates file clipboard.